# Twitter Typeahead set in loop uses first field's URL

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I have a typeahead initialisation function that gets all my typeahead fields and is supposed to set their remote URLs based on a data-url value. However for some reason, it's setting all fields to the first field's url. If I use the console to manually destroy all typeaheads and then target the second field individually, it STILL uses the first field's url.

Using Typeahead 0.9.3

```
function setTypeaheadFields() {
    $.each($("[data-autocomplete]"), function() {
        let input = $(this);
        input.typeahead("destroy");
        let resultField = input.data('inputfield');
        let sourceUrl = input.data('url');
        let minLength = input.data('minLength') || 3;
        console.log(sourceUrl);
        input.typeahead({
            valueKey: 'text',
            name: 'text',
            minLength: minLength,
            remote: {
                url: sourceUrl + '/%QUERY',
                filter: function(parsedResponse) {
                    return parsedResponse;
                },
            template: [
                "<p class='label'><strong>{{text}}</strong></p>"
            ].join(''),
                engine: Hogan
            }
        }).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(e, datum) {
            $(resultField).val(datum.id);
        }).on('typeahead:closed', function() {
            $(resultField).val('');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the "name" field in the options. I wasn't aware that set the name of the typeahead object. All I had to do was set the name programmatically and everything's hunkydory.